# SQL Query Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 5 tables,

Machines(**MachineID**, Name),

Engineers(**EngineerID**, Name),

Parts(**PartID**, Name),

Faults(**FaultID**, *MachineID*, *EngineerID*, Description, Date),

FaultParts(***FaultID, PartID***)

Key = **Primary** (bold), *Foreign Key* (italic), ***Composite*** (italic & bold)

A fault can require more than one part to fix it

I am trying to query the database so that I can retrieve the the engineer name, machine name, fault description, and parts requires to fix.

I am unsure how I should go about doing this efficiently or if may tables should be set up as they are.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, 
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try joining all the relevant tables like:

```
SELECT e.name, m.name, f.description, p.name
FROM Machine m INNER JOIN Faults f ON m.id = f.machineId
INNER JOIN Engineers e ON e.id = f.engineerId
INNER JOIN faultParts fp ON fp.faultId = f.id
INNER JOIN parts p ON p.id = fp.partId
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to start your query from the `faults` tables and join other tables with the required fields as you go. For the multiple parts, you can use an aggregate query with the [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function:

```
SELECT f.description, e.name, m.name, fpp.parts
FROM   faults f
JOIN   engineers e ON f.engineerid = e.engineerid
JOIN   machines m ON f.machineid = m.machineid
JOIN   (SELECT   faultid, GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS parts
        FROM     faultparts fp
        JOIN     parts p ON fp.partid = p.partid
        GROUP BY faultid) fpp ON f.faultid = fpp.faultid
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this stackflow answer may help: [Query results based on multiple records using compound primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089170/query-results-based-on-multiple-records-using-compound-primary-key)

You can do this in a single query by using adding an OR clause for each trio of ids (i.e. for each selected row in your gridview). For example:

```
SELECT whatever 
FROM Table1 
WHERE (KeyCol1=val1-1 AND KeyCol2=val1-2 AND KeyCol3=val1-3) 
OR (KeyCol1=val2-1 AND KeyCol2=val2-2 AND KeyCol3=val2-3) 
OR .. etc
```